# Generating Components Dynamically (Angular 7) for insertion into a DOM

Tags: angular

I need to generate ngx-emoji elements dynamically so that it can be inserted into the dom.

I've generated a hotspot for the insertion, and I'm picking it up by having a reference to it via ViewChild. However, when I try and generate the component via ViewChild it states it is undefined.

I'm following the pattern at https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

I've generated a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pt-inserting-emoji-into-contenteditable-f5bx8x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for the problem.

**EDITED**
Ok, so it is creating the element but it couldn't be seen on the screen. When you inspect what has been created compared to a component that has been instantiated via the template they look very different.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've resolved this. I needed to add change detection step :

```
(<EmojiComponent>comp.instance).ngOnChanges();
```

I'll leave the stackblitz available if anyone is interested.